# Finding an <include> view by id?

Tags: android

Is it possible to find a view by id if it's an ?:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include
      android:id="@+id/foo"
      layout="@layout/test" />

  ...

View view = findViewById(R.id.foo);
```

What is "view" in this case? Is it a view? Does it resolve to whatever the top-level element of "layout/test" is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially overwriting the ID of the top-parent view in the layout your including, so what you'll get is the top-view of the entire layout and it's contents.  The `<include>` tag is, in effect, a copy-and-paste of the contained layout.  You can override the `id` tag and any attribute with `layout_`.

Comment: Should the returned view work ok with View.setVisibility()? Debugging this now, but seems like once I do findViewById(). calling view.setVisibility(View.GONE) has no effect?

Comment: I have never tried that, but I assume it should work.  Every time I've used the tag, I've been able to use it normally for most things.  However, the `visible` property is not one of the ones you can overwrite in xml, so it may not be allowed in this case.

Comment: Yes, you can change the visibility of Views brought in through `include`.

Answer (score 0):

`foo` will be the `id` of the root element (`ViewGroup` or `View`) of `test` layout. If an `id` is already defined for it in `test` layout `foo` will override it.