# How to have a header in every layout page?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I want that this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/logo" style="@style/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/logo" tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

to start in every layout. How can I do that I wouldn't need to add this to every layout page? Like for example in PHP I would use `<?=include("header.php");?>` (just an example, actually it's bad practise, doesn't matter here). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your header in XML file and then include this XML as child layout in other layouts:

```
<include  layout="@layout/headerlayout" android:id="@+id/headerLayoutid"  ...  />
```

The ***headerlayout.xml***  is name of your above layout that should be defined in `res/layout` and you like that be shown as header in all layouts(`layout="@layout/headerlayout"`),also ***headerLayoutid***  is id of your headerlayout(in it's parent) and you can reference to it in your parent layouts or in your code.
You can override all the layout parameters. This means that any `android:layout_*` attribute can be used with the  tag. Here is an example:

```
<include android:layout_width="fill_parent" layout="@layout/image_holder" />
```

You can see more details in about include in [this page](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/).
**Edit**:
If you have problems in about finding views in included layout,see this questions,I hope these help you:
[findViewById not working for an include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803672/findviewbyid-not-working-for-an-include)
[Finding an view by id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184113/finding-an-include-view-by-id)

Answer (score 2):

The `<include>` tag is what you want. Read about it in [Re-using Layouts with `<include/>`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<include .../>` tag in your layout to reuse your header where is needed. See [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.gr/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html) for an example.